# androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialCancellationException: activity is cancelled by the user

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin, credential-manager

Trying to login with the Google Button in my android app using the credential manager, but the login shows the **activity is cancelled by the user** while choosing the gmail account from the popup. But it shows the error as **androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialCancellationException: activity is cancelled by the user.**

Here I have used the web_client_id in the GCP and there is two Android ClientID for the same app.

So I have deleted the AppSigningKey (SHA-1) available client_id and kept the SHA-1 of the already available (i.e) the upload keystore (SHA-1)

```
val googleIdOption: GetSignInWithGoogleOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(WEB_CLIENT_ID).build()
val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder().addCredentialOption(googleIdOption).build()

 R.id.btn_googleSignUp -> {
                val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this@SignUpActivity)
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    try {
                        Log.e("request.. ===", request.toString())
                        val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                            request = request,
                            context = this@SignUpActivity,
                        )
                        handleSignIn(result)
                    } catch (e: GetCredentialCancellationException) {
                        Log.e("CredentialCancelException ===", e.message.toString())
                    } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
                        Log.e("GetCredential ===", e.message.toString())
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e("Exception ===", e.message.toString())
                    }
                }
            }

fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse) {
        // Handle the successfully returned credential.
        val credential = result.credential
        when (credential) {
            is PublicKeyCredential -> {
                // Share responseJson such as a GetCredentialResponse on your server to
                // validate and authenticate
               //responseJson = credential.authenticationResponseJson
            }

            is PasswordCredential -> {
                // Send ID and password to your server to validate and authenticate.
                val username = credential.id
                val password = credential.password
            }

            is CustomCredential -> {
                if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
                    try {
                        // Use googleIdTokenCredential and extract id to validate and
                        // authenticate on your server.
                        val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
                            .createFrom(credential.data)
                    } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                        Log.e("Invalid GoogleId", "Received an invalid google id token response", e)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Catch any unrecognized custom credential type here.
                    Log.e("Unexpected", "Unexpected type of credential")
                }
            }

            else -> {
                // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
                Log.e("Invalid GoogleID", "Unexpected type of credential")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Could you fix it? Same error

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the error for me

Before starting I want to note that this kind of error I as investigated tipically doesn't have relation with the android code itself, is more about the CLIENT_SERVER_ID you are using and the Google Cloud credentials.

- For me was the Android credential
- For other may be that they need to add a user as tester in the oAuth consent screen as shown here https://dev.to/hackmamba/a-beginners-guide-to-oauth-20-with-google-sign-in-enhance-android-app-authentication-2mhi#set-up-google-oauth-20 (not my case as my server is in prod)

My Solution:

I was creating the GetSignInWithGoogleOption using the WEB_SERVER_ID (not the android ID) and that's correct, but it's also necessary to have created the android credential in Google Cloud Console for the app running

In my case I had an "automatically created by Google Service" Android credential and I thought that was correct but it was created for another developer in the past, so I needed to create one for my own

So I went to Google Cloud Console and tap Create Credential -> OAuth Client ID and created an "Android application type".
Package is the package name you can find in the manifest.xml and the SHA1 is a debug one (as i don't have a production one). That SHA1 for your device could be found using this command (replace the path):

> keytool -keystore path-to-debug-keystore -list -v

For MAC would be:

> keytool -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v

The password is "android" for that debug keystore

The documentation that helped with the problem is this:
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=es-419#installedapplications&android&zippy=%2Cnative-applications%2Candroid